# VB.NET Ciphers for Web Services Clients

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tls1.2

I have a VB.NET 4.5 application on Windows Server 2008 R2 that must connect to one of our other internal applications on a Tomcat server via TLSv1.2. According to our security scans and server config (in preparation for PCI), we can only use these ciphers on that server:

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

I have generated the service class from the WSDL as usual, but a Wireshark capture doesn't list any of these ciphers as an option.

My questions:

1. What library does Microsoft.NET use behind the scenes for TLS connections? For example, does it still use SChannel?
2. Is there a way for me to enable / install new ciphers for VB.NET to use?

If it's using SChannel, maybe I can do some registry changes to get it working...? Or is it possible that these ciphers are just not available on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

.NET supports them but by default .NET TLS implementation is using only SSLv3/TLSv1 and it doesn't offer those ciphers.

To enable TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 (not sure which one actually enabled those ciphers) use:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This will enable TLSv1.1+ (and in process disables SSLv3) and .NET should start offering TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

Cheers